# Find all elements on a webpage using powershell/selenium only

Tags: powershell, selenium

I need to use powershell with Selenium.
I am able to get all the elements of any specific Tagname.
But How do i reference a specific element.
Let say for example I want to find the "For developers" button on the homepage and click it.

```html
$browser = Start-SeChrome
$URL = "https://stackoverflow.com/"
$browser.Navigate().GoToURL($URL)
$A_Elements = Find-SeElement -Driver $browser -TagName a
$A_Element = $A_Elements|ForEach-Object{if($_.GetAttribute('Text') -eq 'For developers'){return $_}}
Invoke-SeClick -Driver $browser -Element $A_Element
```

My script fails on the 5th line, as it does not return anything.
Any ideas. Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This finally worked.
It also gives me the advantage of cycling through the elements, whether they are input, span, div etc, and selecting one or more elements as needed.

```html
ForEach ($Input_Element in (Find-SeElement -Driver $browser -TagName input))
   {
   $Input_Element.GetAttribute('id')
   if ($Input_Element.GetAttribute('id') -eq 'login'){$Input_Element.SendKeys($FLogin) }
   if ($Input_Element.GetAttribute('id') -eq 'loginpw'){$Input_Element.SendKeys($Fpass) }
   if ($Input_Element.GetAttribute('id') -eq 'loginsubmit')
      {
      $Input_Element.Click() 
      Break
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are using [Selenium PowerShell Module](https://github.com/adamdriscoll/selenium-powershell).

You should try specifying the element id like this:

```
$Driver = Start-SeChrome 
Enter-SeUrl https://stackoverflow.com/ -Driver $Driver
$Element = Find-SeElement -Driver $Driver -Id "btn"
Invoke-SeClick -Element $Element
```